# How can I properly use $this in object context?

Tags: php, netbeans, web

I'm having a hard time creating a get function in a php class using $this:

```
public function getFxRate($currencyInputCode, $currencyOutputCode) {
    //Getting the currency
    return $this->fxRates[$currencyOutputCode][array_search(1.0, $this->fxRates[$currencyInputCode])];
}
```

The $fxRates array is assigned here:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->ini = parse_ini_file(FXCALC);
    $handle = fopen($this->getIniArray()[self::RATESFILE], 'r');
    $this->fxCurriences = fgetcsv($handle);
    $k = 0;
    for ($i = 0; !feof($handle); $i++) {
        $tempMultiArray[$i] = fgetcsv($handle);
    }
    fclose($handle);

    foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $value) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->getCurrencies()); $i++) {
        $this->fxRates[$value][$i] = $tempMultiArray[$i][$k];
        }
        $k++;
    }
    echo $this->fxRates['CAD'][0];
}
```

And initialized here:

```
private $fxRates = array();
```

I don't understand why $this shows errors for the get function above and yet these two functions work fine:

```
public function getIniArray() {
    return $this->ini;
}

public function getCurrencies() {
    return $this->fxCurriences;
}
```

Here is the error that I'm receiving:

Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpMidtermBP\FxDataModel.php on line 65

Comment: Exactly what is this error message? Given that there's a near infinite number of possible errors, we can't exactly help you with anything other than "fix the error".

Comment: @MarcB Ok I added the error above.

Comment: sigh, which is line 65?????

Comment: @Dagon Line 65 is return $this->return $this->fxRates[$currencyOutputCode][array_search(1.0, $this->fxRates[$currencyInputCode])]; Under the getFxRate function.

Comment: the error message means you're calling the function statically, e.g. `YourObj::getFxRate(...)`. When in static mode, `$this` is not available.

Comment: @MarcB WOW thank you MarcB, that helped me solve my problem which was exactly as you have said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$this refers to an instance yet from the error you're seeing you're calling the method statically.

You would need to instantiate the class and then run your getFxRate method for $this to work.

Eg:

```
$fx = new MyFxClass();
$fx->getFxRate( $arg1, $arg2 );
```